# Grouping the state with NgRx is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I am trying to group the state.

**Index.ts**

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {
  admin: adminReducer
};

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<ApplicationState>[] = [];
```

**Admin Reducer**

```
export const adminReducer: any = {
    productCategory: ProductCategoryReducer,
    productVendor: ProductVendorReducer,
    productSubCategory: ProductSubCategoryReducer,
    products: ProductsReducer,
    product: ProductReducer,
    productDiscount: ProductDiscountReducer
};
```

When I run the application, on redux tool,I am not able to see the state. It is blank

```
export interface ApplicationState {
    admin: AdminState
}

export interface AdminState {
    productCategory: ProductCategoryState;
    productVendor: VendorState;
    productSubCategory: ProductSubCategoryState;
    products: ProductsState;
    product: ProductState;
    productDiscount: ProductDiscountState
}
```

[image]

**Register**

```
    imports: [
        
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25
    })
        
      ]
```

Comment: Have you registed adminReducer inside module StoreModule.forFeature('adminReducer', adminReducer) ?

Comment: Yes, it is register in the appmodule.ts file

Comment: I dont see StoreDevtoolsModule  inside app module imports. Do you added StoreDevtoolsModule inside app.module?

Comment: yes, I used, updated the question

Comment: Why you don't use [combineReducers](https://ngrx.io/api/store/combineReducers) function to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks, I added it as an answer with some details, because it may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reducer` is a *"function that takes an `Action` and a `State`, and returns a `State`"*, not an object, so you can't group the reducers to each other just by creating one object containing them.

Thanks for `NgRx` [combineReducers](https://ngrx.io/api/store/combineReducers) function, which provides a way to combine multiple states, and returns the combined `reducer` as a function (with `state` & `action` args) that handles the sub-states changes and returns the combined state.

So you can simply combine the reducers using `combineReducers` like the following:

```js
export const adminReducer = combineReducers({
    productCategory: ProductCategoryReducer,
    productVendor: ProductVendorReducer,
    productSubCategory: ProductSubCategoryReducer,
    products: ProductsReducer,
    product: ProductReducer,
    productDiscount: ProductDiscountReducer,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [combineReducers](https://ngrx.io/api/store/combineReducers) I achieved that

```
export const adminReducer = combineReducers({
    productCategory: ProductCategoryReducer,
    productVendor: ProductVendorReducer,
    productSubCategory: ProductSubCategoryReducer,
    products: ProductsReducer,
    product: ProductReducer,
    productDiscount: ProductDiscountReducer
});
```